# Solidworks API Assembly Auto print macro

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

is it possible to make VBA Macro: solidworks Assembly print by using solidworks API?
i want to make a program which print from parts to Top assembly

ps. i started studying VBA last week

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You didn't ask a specific question, so you won't get a more specific answer.